# Padding on top and bottom differ (visually) despite both being assigned the same value

Tags: html, css, padding

Easy question for you guys from the beginner: why are there different sizes of top and bottom padding and they are not in the center of div?

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.splash {
  background: green;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1140px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.0.0/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="splash">
    <div class="container">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-user-secret"></i>
      <h1 class="page-title">First paragraph </h1>
      <h2 class="page-subtitle">Second paragraph</h2>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

I thought I would result in equal paddings on the top and bottom but nope.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "equal paddings on the top and bottom"? When I run this code the padding is equal and the .container is centered in the the .splash. Do you mean that there is more space on the sides of the .container than the top/bottom? If so, it's because of the max-width that is set on the container.

Answer (score 0):

just by how your code is structured, i can tell that the extra padding you are getting is coming from this header,

```
<h2 class="page-subtitle">Second paragraph</h2>
```

it's default margin is overflowing out of your div container.

you can't just stack headers like that, try adding this to your css

```
.page-subtitle{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

if you need me to calrify or if i misundertood what you are trying to do, please let know in the comments

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, then removing all margin on the `h2` then means the padding is equal on both top and bottom for `.splash`

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.splash {
  background: green;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1140px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
}

.page-subtitle {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.0.0/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="splash">
    <div class="container">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-user-secret"></i>
      <h1 class="page-title">First paragraph </h1>
      <h2 class="page-subtitle">Second paragraph</h2>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```